# Cucumber 7 get step name in BeforeStep hook

Tags: java, cucumber, testng

in our current framework we run Cucumber 4 and have a particular function to obtain the current step name in the BeforeStep hook, this is done for logging. Because of several vulnerabilities I am upgrading Cucumber to version 7 but this function got completely broken.

Is there a way to obtain the current step name from the BeforeStep hook to log it? Thanks in advance!

I already tried using the PickleStepTestStep without luck, also passing the TestCaseStarted event as an argument to try access the step name through it but it looks like the only argument that we can use for that hook is the Scenario itself which has no information regarding the steps name. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

We Can add **Listner** and Call it in **TestRunner** class. Below is the demonstration that we can use the **TestStepStarted** plugin event to log the test step text in **Cucumber 7.**

[Full Guide to Log Step Using **TestStepStarted** Event](https://qatestauto.com/cucumber-7-get-the-step-name-in-the-beforestep-hook-teststepstarted-event-in-cucumber/)

I hope this will help you!